# Sharepoint Designer how to make a link to element from another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How to made a Hyperlink in SharePoint Designer to another element from the list?

I have got joined two lists, and now I only want to create a link which show only this elements from second list which I clicked on Hyperlink:

[image]

Comment: It is still very unsure what you are asking and it is a duplicate of your previous post(s)

Comment: I deleted that posts. I ask only for link to the element in another sharepoint list

Comment: That does not really say a lot. What other list, what type of link, what element?

Comment: I must do a link for custom list from another custom list and link to the title showing all elements with the same title.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by:

```
        <td class="ms-vb">

                 <a href="http://YourServerName/Lists/Product/DisplayForm.aspx?ID={@ID}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
   </a></td>
```

Now i dot't know how to read id like in EditForm.